# Loop through each cell in a selected range

Tags: excel, visual-studio

I'm trying to make a procedure in Visual studio for looping through a range not named into Excel.
For example the user selects "A1" & "A5" "A94". In my procedure I can see the range.count prorperty as value 3, but if I make a Do Loop I can't take the second cell value of the selected range but I find "A2".
My procedure is this:

```
    Dim counter As Integer = 1
    Dim ActiveCell As Excel.Range

    Do
        ActiveCell = SelectedRange.Item(counter)
        ActiveCell.Select()
        MessageBox.Show(ActiveCell.Value2.ToString)
        counter = counter + 1
    Loop While counter <= SelectedRange.Count
    SelectedRange.Select()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example sub which sets the value of every selected cell to 1:

```
Sub EditSelection()
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In Selection
        rng.Value = 1
    Next rng
End Sub
```

Let me know if you're still struggling after that